# Rotate a control in android

Tags: android

I create a control who will get the signature of the user and then it returns me a bitmap with the signature and finally I print a receipt.

So I have an Activity who only supports portrait orientation and I need that when I show the Signature control, it be in landscape mode. I can´t use other Activity just because my app always ask for login if the user lost the focus of the first activity and I need the signature as a part of a transaction.

I don't know if I can rotate the controls to simulate the landscape orientation and I didn't find information about this.

*I only have to show the control in landscape and the control always use all the screen.

Comment: try something like that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377260/how-can-i-rotate-display-only-in-landscape-mode-in-android and do some research this is common question !!

Comment: Yes u can rotate the control, but still I would recommend supporting both orientations in your `Activity`. If you do this properly you won't looser any of your data or session. Here is a quick search on  Google: https://www.google.com/search?q=save+state+on+orientation+change+&oq=save+state+on+orientation+change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi May be this will help...

If you want to your screen in portrait..

In your manifest  `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`

or In Your Coding `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`

If you want to your screen in landscape..

In your manifest  `android:screenOrientation="landscape"`

or In Your Coding `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);`

If your activity don't want to restart every time while changing orientation of mobile try below line in your manifest..

```
<activity android:name="Your Activity"
             android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

Comment: So, Can I do something like block the orientation and then rotate the activity programatically when I want to do it. This to use portrait orientation in all the activity unless when I have to ask the user for the signature?

Comment: thanks, I´m looking for information about that, I think it will solve my problem.
Also thanks Yume117 and M-WaJeEh

Comment: If my ans really helpful to you ple accept it ... it'll helpful for some others also...